# Unresponsive script message on main Stack Overflow page

Tags: bug, status-declined

I am not sure if this is good place to post this, but...

I have updated my Firefox (49.0b2) two days ago and ever since I keep getting the *Unresponsive script* warning every 5-10 minutes or so when on the main Stack Overflowpage (https://stackoverflow.com/questions).

This is small list of scripts popping up:

```
Script: http://ajax.googleapis.com/aja…ibs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:2
Script: resource://gre/modules/commonj…ad38a/data/mutation-summary.js:278
Script: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=f2c08d3f1ec4:1
Script: resource://gre/modules/commonj…ad38a/data/mutation-summary.js:209
Script: resource://gre/modules/commonj…ad38a/data/mutation-summary.js:36
```

And a screenshot:

[image]

I can see this only happening on the Stack Overflow page and nowhere else. Is the issue on the Stack Overflow site?

Comment: As noted in [the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332180/1583) by David - browsers in beta/development status are not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I have updated my Firefox (49.0b2) two days ago and ever since I keep getting Unresponsive script warning

Beta and development releases of browsers are **not** supported.

Any bug report will probably be marked [status-declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-declined)

> we support the last two versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use. This does not include beta/dev releases, which are not supported.

Source: answer to [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)